# Can't create item receipt in NetSuite using SuiteScript 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript1.0

So, i'm trying to create a Item Receipt on my NetSuite instance using SuiteScript 1.0, and i'm receiving this error message:

```
{\"success\":false,\"errorMessage\":\"\\nCode: SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION\\nDetails: You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.\"}"
```

So, i do not understand a lot of NetSuite, but i think static lists can't be modified. If that's the case, then how am i supposed to create a Item Receipt through SuiteScript if i can't add the items?

Below are my scripts, and the Postman Json request that i'm using:

SuiteScript:

```
function createItemReceipt(dataIn) {
    try {
        var record = nlapiCreateRecord('itemreceipt', {recordmode: 'dynamic'});
        record.setFieldValue('entity', dataIn.entity);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < dataIn.items.length; i++) {
            var item = dataIn.items[i];
            record.selectNewLineItem('item');
            record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', item.itemId);
            record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', item.quantity);
            record.commitLineItem('item');
        }
        var recordId = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true, true);
        
        return {
            success: true,
            recordId: recordId
        };
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            success: false,
            errorMessage: e.toString()
        };
    }
}

function post(dataIn) {
    var response = createItemReceipt(dataIn);
    return JSON.stringify(response);
}
```

Json payload:

```
    {
      "entity": "123",
      "items": [
        {
          "itemId": "456",
          "quantity": 10
        },
        {
          "itemId": "789",
       

   "quantity": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item receipts in NetSuite are rarely, if ever, created as standalone records.  The typical way they are created is to *transform* a purchase order, or a transfer order.  To do this, use the `nlapiTransformRecord(type, id, transformType, transformValues)` instead of `nlapiCreateRecord`.

The documentation for SS1.0 has been removed from SuiteAnswers HTML and packaged  into a PDF reference.  This can be found at https://{{accountid}}.app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/shared_resources/PDF/SuiteScript10API.pdf?whence=.  Search in there for `nlapiTransformRecord`.

I've partially reproduced the relevant section below, but the documentation has more, including examples - so look that up also if you can.

> ### nlapiTransformRecord(type, id, transformType, transformValues)
>
> Initializes a new record using data from an existing record of a
> different type and returns an nlobjRecord. This function can be useful
> for automated order processing such as creating item fulfillment
> transactions and invoices off of orders.
>
> This API is supported in
> client, user event, scheduled, and Suitelet scripts. See the help
> topic SuiteScript
> 1.0 API Governance for the unit cost associated with this API.
>
> For a list of supported transform types, see Supported Transformation Types.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - type {string} [required] - The record internal ID name.
>   In the NetSuite Help Center, see the help topic SuiteScript Supported
>   Records. The internal ID appears in the column called “Record Internal
>   ID”.
> - id {int} [required] - The internalId for the record, for
>   example 555 or 78.
> - transformType {string} [required] - The record
>   internal ID name of the record you are transforming the existing
>   record into
> - transformValues {hashtable} [optional] - An array of field name -> value pairs containing field defaults
>   used for transformation. Note that you can also specify whether you want the record transformation
>   to occur in dynamic mode. For details, see the help topic SuiteScript 1.0 Working with Records in
>   Dynamic Mode.

Comment: Thank you @Krypton, i was able to transform the PO into a valid Item Receipt with this method you informed!